# Effect culling on uneven terrain

Tags: unity, particles, graphic-effects

I'm trying to integrate a "ground particle" effect (like a fire-circle or similar) in Unity3d, however since i'm using uneven terrain as my terrain mesh, the effect gets culled behind terrain parts that above it.

To better ilustrate it I created an image as attachment : [image] 
I want for the effect to always be displayed regardless of it's "depth".
How can this undesired effect be avoided/resolved properly ?

Comment: It looks like you're projecting your effect to the bottom of your actor. I would think you'd want to display it to the terrain below your actor. The visible part, by your illustration, would be floating above the terrain, which wouldn't look good either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend an animated [Projector](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Projector.html).

You'd simply configure the IgnoreLayers property to ignore your player. And you could animate the effect with a simple script to modify the UV offsets of the material you use.

One thing to remember is for every object a projector is projected onto an extra draw call is issued (just like a light), so use them sparingly.

Answer (score 0):

If the effect is simply a quad being created at the player's feet, then you will have to change the way your effect is implemented. Projecting the effect onto the surface like a decal is one way to get things looking a bit better. Of course, it won't help with extra particles, or other more complex effects. Here is a link describing this idea.

http://blog.wolfire.com/2009/06/how-to-project-decals/

Comment: Yes , i already use this scenario ( albeit with using projectors , but more or less), but as you noted in your post , in my case I'm using a 'complex' effect (rotation on the ground texture along with 'flame tongues' emitters.).